# Why does new Array(3) == ",,"; return true

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found a weired question: `new Array(3) == ',,';//true`, and i don't know why is that.

I already know a number passed in function `Array` means to create a new specific length empty array, and I have no idea what `',,'` mean? and I google it but no answer.

so I come to stack overflow, somebody may help me, I guess

Comment: comparing to string, it the array is coerced to a string (`.toString()` method) ... now, what is `new Array(3).toString())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the the `toString()` method is invoked on the array instance when you are comparing with the ***loose*** equality operator. The `==` operator uses the [Abstract Equality comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

The operand on the left is being *coerced* to the type on the right of the `==` operator by calling the `toString()`.

The `toString()` internally calls `Array.prototype.join()` on the array instance and since you have only *holes* in your array, the output is two commas as a string `,,` :

```js
//Outputs ,, to the console
console.log(new Array(3).toString()); 

//The toString() is calling join()
console.log(new Array(3).join() === new Array(3).toString());
```

If you do the same with the strict equality operator this won't be the case as type coercion won't happen:

```js
//coercion is happening due to the loose equality operator
console.log(new Array(3) == ',,')  
 //strict equality does not call toString() on the Array as no type coercion happens
console.log(new Array(3) === ',,')
```

The `toString()` as I mentioned before calls the `Array.prototype.join()` so that is why you get `,,` as the output of `Array.prototype.toString()`.

The `join()` when called  without any parameters will join the elements of the array using the default separator `,`. In case of an empty array it will join the holes with `,`:

```js
//This will also be true
console.log([1, 2, 3] == '1,2,3')

//toString() converts array to a string by joining with the default separator internally calling join()
console.log([1, 2, 3].toString() === '1,2,3')

//join() converts array to a string by joining with the default separator
console.log([1, 2, 3].join() === '1,2,3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `==` operator and are comparing an array to string, 
what really happens is that the array is converted to a string using `new Array(3).toString()` and is equal to `',,'`.

Using the `===` would end up with a false result.